# Where can I find the Javadoc for Spring Boot Annotation @SpringBootTest (ie, for Package org.springframework.boot.test.context)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've found a useful blog post describing testing improvements in Spring Boot 1.4 (I don't have enough reputation points to include the link), but the Java APIs at http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/ don't seem to contain some of the annotations referred to, including @SpringBootTest. I've also checked the version for 1.4.0.M3 with the same result.  Many thanks for any help.

Comment: It might help including the link to the blog? Also note that Spring Boot 1.4 is still in development, so things that might have been in a M1 release might not be around in a newer release.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on the reference of the pre release of spring boot. There is a section "testing" where you could find first information and usage:
[Spring boot pre 1.4.0 reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.M3/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing)